# Android : Google Play APK 2.3.4

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have accidently deleted ‘Google Play’ App from my android phone (2.3.4) and now I am not able to download/upgrade any app from store even though I have ‘Market’ App installed. I am getting pop up ‘An error has occurred. Please try again later’ when trying to upgrade any app (e.g. Whatsapp) or directly clicked on ‘Market’ app.
Kindly help me how to resolve this issue. Is there any way, I can install Google Play APK on my Android 2.3.4

Regards,
BK

Comment: From where can I get APK for Google Play and how to install it?

Answer (score 0):

To reinstall the Google Play app to your device, you can follow these steps.

First, you need to get an APK installer on your device if you don't already have one. I use the app "APK Installer" from this site: http://apkinstaller.com/ I've used this app quite a bit in development and highly recommend it.

You can download their PC software which will allow you to install APKs to your device through a USB connection. You can follow their detailed instructions on how to do this here: http://apkinstaller.com/faqs/how-to-install-apk.html

Once you have done this, you can download the latest version of the Google Play app and install it onto your device using the APK Installer. Grab the latest version of the app (or whatever version you need) from a mirror site such as this: http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-5-6-8-android-apk-download/

Once you get the Google Play app back on your device, sign into it with your Google account, and all your apps should be able to update again.

Hope this helps!